# How to sort by json field in Spring data jpa?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

I am using spring data jpa specification query to do dynamic query

I have a problem that is i need to sort by a json field and
I searched a lot at google but still no idea how to do that

It is very easy to be done by the sql :

```
select * , JSON_EXTRACT(json_column, '$.age') as age from table order by  age desc ;
```

Any ideas ? Thanks you all.

Answer (score 5):

I just found another way to do that.
Here is the solution:

```
@Entity
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Expert extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String code;

    @Formula(value = "JSON_EXTRACT(expert_information, '$.basicInformation.nameEN')")
    private String age;

    @Type(type = "json")
    @Column(columnDefinition = "json", nullable = false)
    private Map<String, Object> expertInformation;
}
```

The key of this solution is to use the @Formula anotation. In that anotation use the json function to extract it as a normal property.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to make `age` a normal persistent property.

You can achieve that by creating a 2 column database view with id and age columns, with the age column based on JSON_EXTRACT as in your question.

You can then use `@SecondaryTable` on your entity so that it is can be mapped to both its table and the view you have just created, joined on the id columns.

You can then make age a persistent property. You can then sort on filter on age as you would for any other persistent property.

```
@Entity
@Table("...")
@SecondaryTable("my_new_view")
public class MyEntity{

    //existing mappings

    @Column(name ="age" table="my_new_view", insertable="false", updateable="false")
    private Integer age; //ensure to use wrapper type here to avoid issues
}
```

Comment: Thank your reply. But I found a another way to do that.